# Display .txt to textbox without selection

Tags: matlab, user-interface, path

I have a `static textbox` and `pushbutton` in my MATLAB GUI. I'm trying to open .txt file from desktop to `textbox` in GUI.

I mean  when I push the button I want to read my .txt file in `textbox`. I don't want to select file. Just display the txt file in `textbox` when pushed.

I know this code -

```
[filename pathname] = uigetfile ({'*.txt'},'File Selector');
fullpathname = strcat(pathname,filename);
text = fileread(fullpathname);
set(handles.text68, 'String' , text )
```

This is selecting a file. I just want to display without selection.

Can you help me please ? I have to do this for my final project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the path (eg: /home/yourname/Desktop/) and filename (eg: textToDisplay.txt)of your text to display you can delete your two first line and replace the third line by:

```
text = fileread('/home/yourname/Desktop/textToDisplay.txt');
```